# How to create a hot folder to execute incoming, differently named batch files?

Tags: automation, imagemagick, dos, batch-processing

Basically, I need to have a script running that watches for new .bat files in a folder, runs them in the command prompt, and deletes or moves them. As stated in the title the names of the .bat files will vary, the only thing in common will be the .bat extension.

This is on Windows, DOS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and write a simple script to watch the directory for .bat files. if new files are added, you can execute them or delete/move them. Easy to code and extremely fast and reliable. Or you could use Java1.7's WatchService. Check [here](http://e-blog-java.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-watch-file-system-for-changes-in.html) for an example

Comment: Thanks for responding- I will check into that route. I'm not much of a coder, so I'm more curious about how to actually create this code. I've found examples, but I'm stuck on the syntax to run a non-specifically named file, or even something with a variable in the name, like orderXXXX.bat, xxxx being an order number.